# Can't view newly added shared Google calendars from co-workers

Tags: google-calendar

I have shared several work calendars in Google Calendars with my boss who is an AOL user. He linked his AOL account to a generic Google account – received the email invitation to that calendar, we can get to the calendar settings page – we press "save" and "back to calendar" but he says it is not showing up.

I'm sure we're missing something really minor – but what is it?

Comment: Asking in a comment first because it's basic, but did you make sure the boss' "My Calendars" menu is open on the left nav tray? If it's collapsed, click the triangle on the left to expand it and perhaps the calendars are listed there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have shared *YOUR* calendar with your boss' *GMail* account, and they have then shared their *Gmail* calendar to their *AOL* Account, you are not going to see *YOUR* calendar on their *AOL* calendar

The reason is that they are not sharing "everything that I can see" with the *AOL* calendar.

All they are actually sharing is "events that are currently on *GMail* calendar".

So if you want them to be able to see your events you have to share your calendars directly with their *AOL* account (or, give them rights to Share your Calendar via their *GMail* account)